# cmake fails to configure with a pthread error

Tags: cmake, pthreads

I am trying to configure a project using cmake and Im getting an error. The content in CMakeError.log is the following

```
Change Dir: /home/jjcasmar/D/libs/builds/sofa/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9feda/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/D/jjcasmar/libs/builds/sofa/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/jjcasmar/D/libs/builds/sofa/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
Linking C executable cmTC_9feda
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_9feda 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':
src.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9feda.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_9feda] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/D/jjcasmar/libs/builds/sofa/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_9feda/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Nevertheless, it says compiler accepts -pthread correctly

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "3.8.2")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE
```

I have tried a very simple CMakeLists (below) to check if pthreads was working fine and looks like is working fine (configures and builds fine)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Test)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(Test a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test Threads::Threads)
```

with the following output when I configure

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

I am not sure how to find what is the cause of the issue. Any idea would be helpful

Comment: I can confirm that your sample works correctly on my machine with cmake 3.15.5. Notice that it says `-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed` but cc is called with `DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD`. Is this ok?

Comment: And there is also no `-lpthread` anywhere. Locally I get this when running `make VERBOSE=1`: `/usr/local/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/Test.dir/a.cpp.o  -o Test -lpthread`.

Comment: The test I did is working fine. The problem must be in the big project, but that was running fnie also until yesterday. Not sure where to start looking at

Comment: I don't know your project so I cannot say and you may not be able show it here, and even if you could it would probably be too big for anyone to find a bug quickly but for starters you could remove all Cmake cache and run build once again. I'd investigate `-DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD`, it looks suspicious to me. Do you also see it when running the minimal example you posted?

Comment: And if you use `Git` or some other version control system check all recent changes to the build system. If you work in a bigger and multicultural team it's possible that someone has committed something wrong overnight.

Comment: Im not sure what was wrong, I reset completely the source code (somehow it changes a ExternalProjects.cmake file) and that solved it.